# Writing an auto-memoizer in Scheme. Help with macro and a wrapper

Tags: functional-programming, macros, scheme, racket

I am facing a couple of problems while writing an auto-memoizer in Scheme.

I have a working memoizer function, which creats a hash table and checks if the value is already computed. If it has been computed before then it returns the value else it calls the function.

```
(define (memoizer fun)
  (let ((a-table (make-hash)))
    (λ(n)
      (define false-if-fail (λ() #f))
      (let ((return-val (hash-ref a-table n false-if-fail)))
        (if return-val
            return-val
            (begin
              (hash-set! a-table n (fun n))
              (hash-ref a-table n)))))))
```

Now I want to create a memoize-wrapper function like this:

```
(define (memoize-wrapper function)
  (set! function (memoizer function)))
```

And hopefully create a macro called def-memo which defines the function with the memoize-wrapper. eg. the macro could expand to (memoizer (define function-name arguments body ...) or something like that.

So that I should be able to do :

```
(def-memo (factorial n)
  (cond
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (else (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
```

which should create a memoized version of the factorial instead of the normal slow one.

My problem is that the

1. The memoize-wrapper is not working properly, it doesnt call the memoized function but the original function.
2. I have no idea how to write a define inside of the macro. How do I make sure that I can get variable lenght arguments and variable length body? How do I then define the function and wrap it around with the memoizer?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is what i use in PLT scheme:

```
#lang scheme

(define (memo f)
  (define mh (make-hash))
  (lambda p
    (hash-ref mh p (lambda ()
                     (hash-set! mh p (apply f p))
                     (hash-ref mh p)))))

(define-syntax-rule (defmemo (id . p) . body)
  (define id (memo (lambda p . body))))

(provide defmemo)
```

Comment: WOW. That is just awesome. Could you briefly comment your code especially the macro bit. Why are there . ? why did you provide? And do you really need apply? I am a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: In a parameter list, . indicates that the following variable is bound to more than one thing. In the macro, p is a list of params, not just a single param (body is a list of expressions). Same thing in the function, apply is needed to apply p, a list of params, to the function f.

Comment: See also this: http://planet.plt-scheme.org/display.ss?package=memoize.plt&owner=dherman

Comment: Oh, and BTW, note that memoization is not always so straightforward; you might want to memoize based on argument identities (eg, use an `eq?` hash table), or only on some arguments, or use a weak hash table to avoid memory leaks, etc etc.  Also, the above solution might be slow for various reasons (like using a rest argument, or a single hash table for the lookup of all arguments which can mean a very loaded table).