# What is the difference between make-hash make-weak-hash in racket?

Tags: racket

Found this while looking for a memoizing function:

```
#lang scheme

(define (memo f)
  (define mh (make-hash))
  (lambda p
    (hash-ref mh p (lambda ()
                     (hash-set! mh p (apply f p))
                     (hash-ref mh p)))))

(define-syntax-rule (defmemo (id . p) . body)
  (define id (memo (lambda p . body))))

(provide defmemo)
```

as seen here: [Writing an auto-memoizer in Scheme. Help with macro and a wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066414/writing-an-auto-memoizer-in-scheme-help-with-macro-and-a-wrapper)

However in the documentation there's also: make-weak-hash and make-immutable-hash. Which hash function is better for memoization?

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

I would say for memoization sticking with `make-hash` is your best bet. The other options are used for different purposes.

- `make-immutable-hash` is for making, well, you guessed it, immutable hash tables. The hash tables it creates are the same as if you had created them with `hash`. Of course, the items 'in' the table can still be mutable, such as if you put a mutable struct in there. Its just that the table itself is not mutable.
- `make-hash` is used for making mutable hash tables. This is probably what you want here since you are mutating your memoization table.
- `make-weak-hash` is actually completely different. Specifically, it stores 'weak' pointers to the items in the table. That is, it does not count as a pointer as far as the garbage collector is concerned. So, if you use them, your items may end up being collected. (This doesn't mean you'll get a segfault, you just may lose your data.) Thus, you generally don't want this table unless you know you specifically want this behavior.

Comment: where would  `make-weak-hash` be used?

Comment: Any time you don't want the GC to keep your object only because its in your table. For example, if you are implementing a finalizer, you might want to use make-weak-hash.